# httpwebrequest null proxy settings

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest

I am developing a program, it must work at different networks.
I have a problem with proxy settings. 
when I set proxy to null at intranet,

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
```

httpwebrequest doesn't respond; however when I work at internet, I need to set it to null.

I have solved this problem that I am making request, If there is no response, I set the proxy to null.
But this solution can make problems, there must be better solution.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: you should let the user set up the proxy, either from the application configuration file or from a custom UI, depending on your kine of application.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is pick up the default credentials setup by the user on the system:

```
svc.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
if (svc.Proxy != null)
  svc.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Comment: I tried your advice however I think it can't get default settings because webrequest response is extremely slow.